# addEventListener not working with 'this'

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a project involving generating and changing a `<div>`. Anyways, it would be a pain to have to do `<div id="drawn" onclick="changeColor(this)"></div>` for 80 divs which I am working with.

I decided  to use the `addEventListener()` function to enable an events to happen when clicked.

What I am trying to do is when a `<div>` is clicked, the color of it's background is changed.

When I try the code I am using, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined ' of null` in the Javascript Console.

Here is my code:

```
function color(elment) {

elment.style.backgroundColor="orange"

}

document.getElementById("drawn").addEventListener("click", color(this), false)
```

What is causing the error in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you don't affect a function handler to your event, you're executing it. Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById("drawn").addEventListener("click", function() { color(this); }, false)
```

But since you have 80 divs, from the resources point of view, it would be best to define a specific function designed to change the color of the parent div automatically, with no need of a parameter:

```
function changeDivColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor="orange"
}
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById("drawn").addEventListener("click", changeDivColor, false);
```

would result into the 80 divs calling the same handler, while the previous system would instanciate 80 anonymous handlers doing basically the same thing.

edit: funny how @elclanrs and I just posted the same edits at the same exact time :-)

Comment: I have used the above code, but I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`. Here is my [Pastebin-Code](http://pastebin.com/r3h1Zp4W) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Alright, I did a little bit of editing. Since I appended all the little divs (id'd drawn) inside rows inside of a table, somehow, the divs will not change to orange. Anything outside of the table will always turn to orange though.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not the best with JsFiddle (never used it).

Comment: @JacobKodner also, there's no `range` in javascript... your code does not work, but I think I answered your original question in the context it had at that time. I suggest you open another question if you experience further javascript issues. (and also, if you can, upvote + accept my answer, would be great. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an anonymous function, otherwise the context of `this` is `window` not the element:

```
document.getElementById("drawn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  color(this);
}, false);
```

What you can do is just use the context in your `color` function:

```
function color() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

document.getElementById("drawn").addEventListener("click", color, false);
```

Comment: I have used the above code, but I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`. Here is my [Pastebin-Code](http://pastebin.com/r3h1Zp4W) if you want to take a look.

Comment: You probably don't have an element with id `drawn`.

Comment: Alright, I did a little bit of editing. Since I appended all the little divs (id'd drawn) inside rows inside of a table, somehow, the divs will not change to orange. Anything outside of the table will always turn to orange though.